# Opera Spatial Navigation: Ignore/Disable a navigation event

Tags: css, navigation, opera, keyboard-events

I am developing an interactive interface to run on a set top box using Opera 12, with my development happening in Opera 12.12.

I am leveraging Opera's spatial navigation for navigating around the interface (see https://dev.opera.com/tv/tweaking-spatial-navigation-for-tv-browsing/ for more info). This is all done through CSS using the `nav-[up:down:left:right]` properties.

Here's a very basic example:

```
<a id="1" href="#" style="nav-up: #3; nav-right: #2;">Link 1</a>
<a id="2" href="#">Link 2</a>
<a id="3" href="#">Link 3</a>
```

If `Link 1` has focus and the user navigates `Right` (using a remote control), the focus will jump to `Link 2`. If `Link 1` has focus and the user navigates `Up`, the focus will jump to `Link 3`. If `Link 1` has focus and the user navigates either `Down` or `Left`, the browsers default "next logical element" navigation kicks in (because `nav-down` and `nav-left` haven't been specified). This action is not desirable, as that element could be a completely separate menu/div/list anywhere on the page, and I want to have full control over how the user navigates around.

I have tried leaving the `nav` properties empty:

```
<a id="1" href="#" style="nav-up: #3; nav-down: ; nav-left: ; nav-right: #2;">Link 1</a>
```

or

```
<a id="1" href="#" style="nav-up: #3; nav-down: #; nav-right: #2; nav-left: #;">Link 1</a>
```

but in both situations the defualt navigation kicks in. I have a solution where the properties reference itself:

```
<a id="1" href="#" style="nav-up: #3; nav-down: #1; nav-right: #2; nav-left: #1;">Link 1</a>
```

This works, however I'm wondering if there is another solution to this. Can a navigation event be ignored using the same coding method?